# "Related Content" stored in which object / How to create "Related Content" records from Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

If you navigate to account/contact/custom object we do have a related list "related content" (if content is enabled and related list is added to page layout).

My question is were are these "related content" records stored? in which object?

Using apex I'm able to upload file to content version, but not able to create or find the object which stores the "related content" information.

**UPDATE**

Tried to create a link to show up in "related content" section of account, but no success. Got error " Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You cannot create a link for this type of entity through the api: [LinkedEntityId]"

Any idea?

```
           ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
            versionData = EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(base64BlobValue),
            Title = fileName,
            PathOnClient = '/'+fileName,
            FirstPublishLocationId = '058900000009KcL'
        );
        insert cv;

        //fetch ContentDocumentId
        cv = [Select Id,ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where Id = :cv.Id];

        insert new ContentDocumentLink(LinkedEntityId=parentId,ContentDocumentId=cv.ContentDocumentId,ShareType='V');
```

** USE CASE **

The use case is to allow user to attach content right from object detail page for eg say Account will have button say Attach Content, this will bring upload content page, once uploaded (i will create contentversion records - this is happening perfectly, no errors) and then I need to relate the uploaded content to account (from which request orginated) ie create "related content" records (here I'm facing difficulty, trying to create contentdocumentlink records but its erroring out).

The use case is just one click to attach content to account or opportunity instead of long current process were user goes to content, uploads there first and then comes back to account/opty and searches content again, and then attaches it to account/contact.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I have the same scenario

Comment: Hi @Chirag, I was successfully able to use your code to convert an attachment into a `ContentVersion` and relate it to the Account (attachment's parent). I did this in Winter '16 org API v35. The one change I did make was that I did not try to create the ContentVersion with the `FirstPublishLocationId` field. Thanks for your code sample!

Answer (score 2):

As you know the content is stored in the `ContentDocument` object and the links are stored in the `ContentDocumentLink` table.

I find that the http://workbench.developerforce.com really useful for figuring out these kinds of relationships.

Comment: I tried to insert in the same CDL object, but seems I'm missing something. Please check original post, I've updated the same with the code I been trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the [ContentDocumentLink specification](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) in the user docs, `LinkedEntityId` represents:

```
ID of the linked object. Can include Chatter users, groups, records
(any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects),
and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.
```

I'm thinking that based on that explanation, you can *only create the ContentDocumentLink for Chatter based object fields, not for regular sObject records or custom sobjects*, etc.

Comment: Even after enabling chatter feed for custom object, it produce same error. Does anyone has way to acheive file creation for custom object?